# how to escape curly braces in Json?

Tags: json, jinja2

my code looks like this:

```
"Control Statements": [
            {
                "key": " {% for foo in foo1 %} ... {% endfor %}",
                "val": "For loop"
            },
            {
                "key": "{% foo %} ... {% endif %}",
                "val": "If statement"
            }
         ]
```

I want to escape curly braces in the "key part"

Comment: Can you clarify this question? Are these getting rendered in a template? What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes it is to be rendered.. i have got my answer. it worked well using \\ before "{" and "}".  `"key": " \\{% foo %\\}...\\{% endif %//}`

Comment: @AYUSHKUMAR Can you please edit your question  to clarify this, instead of through a comment? The answer you stated doesn't appear here. So can you please also add an answer and mark it as a solution? Stack Overflow isn't just a site for you to solve your problem and move on. It's a community where everyone helps each other to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works using \\ before "{" and "}".

eg:

`"key": " \\{% foo %\\}...\\{% endif %//}`

Answer (score 0):

You escape json braces { } by adding additional ones {{ }}.
I assume you could some online utility to help you escape json characters easily.

Comment: What do you mean? If my template looks like `{{ foo }}`, and I want the output to be literally `{{ foo }}`, do I do `{{ { }}{{ { }} foo {{ } }}{{ } }}`?

Answer (score 0):

Use "\uXXXX" notation for any character you want instead of XXXX you need to put hexadecimal unicode code of character.

<{> has code 0x7b and <}> is 0x7d.
So "\u007b" and "\u007d"

Comment: That didn't work for me. The output is still `\u00xx`, instead of `{` and `}`. Jinja didn't convert those characters into curly braces.